# In Selenium Webdriver how to handle this kind of multi select dropdown which contains checkbox

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a drop down as shown in snap below

[image]

I Need to handle the multiselect by clicking on the checkbox corresponding to the name. 
I am using data-driven framework. I am fetching data from excel.
Right now I have written code to click on the arrow in the drop down and then click on the corresponding checkbox. I need a better solution to handle multiple selection like this.

Comment: Tell us what you have tried (with some *relevant code*). Also, the source of the page is a little more helpful than the screenshot. (But I'd retain the screenshot as well).

Comment: Hi... I have some sample example..      http://selenium.polteq.com/en/controlling-a-selectbox-or-dropdownbox-with-selenium-webdriver/                                      http://www.abodeqa.com/2013/02/28/how-to-handle-drop-down-in-webdriver/#more-563              Hope you can get solution...

Comment: You should at least include what the html looks like after you click on the drop down.

Answer (score 1):

Having done some research, I'm going to assume that this multiple-select dropdown is the one provided by this jQuery plugin:

**http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2013/05/how-to-make-multiple-select-dropdown-list-jquery.html**

You can find an example where you can inspect the elements here:

**http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/**

Each checkbox can be found with an xpath like this:

```bash
//label[contains(text(), 'Name of Option goes Here')]//input
```

After you open the dropdown list, you can then use a for loop in your code and select each element by an xpath:

```java
public void selectOptions(String... options) {
    //code to open dropdown goes here
    for(String option : options) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(), '" + option + "')]//input")).click();
    }
}
```

(Note: you may also want to include the WebDriver as a parameter of this method and make the method static, depending on how your class is set up.)

Comment: Also, let me know if the html code you're dealing with is significantly different from the jQuery plugin example I found, so I can change my answer.

Answer (score 0):

1) Click on the arrow on the drop down, drop down list will open.

2) Take the entire drop down list in to an Webelement.

3) Create a WebElement list under the above WebElement, where tag name equals to "tr" / "li" (Depends on your html code). Now this list contains all the multiselect entries of the drop down.

4) Get the text of each WebElement in the above WebElement list.

5) Read the data from Excel.

6) Where the data from point (4) & point (5) are equal, click on the respective check box using XPATH.

If u need further explanation post the source of the drop down.
or
Give any webaddress having the same type of drop down.